# Definition of a Denumerably categorical set of sentences

Tags: logic, definition

Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey in "Computability and Logic" on page 147 define

> > A set $\Gamma$ is *denumerably categorical* if any two denumerable models are isomorphic.

What does this definition mean? (As stated: If you can find any two isomorphic models, then the  set $\Gamma$ is denumerably categorical.)

My question is in the other direction: Is it correct to say: if a set of sentences is denumerably categorical, then all denumerable models are isomorphic?

Thanks

Comment: Catagorical? Not categorical maybe?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I never could spell, and barely read. Embarrassing to be corrected by someone whose first language doesn't even use vowels.

Comment: That's not accurate. We have vowels. They're just more limited, and don't provide a full description of the pronunciation. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're reading "any two denumerable models are isomorphic" to mean "there exist denumerable models $M$ and $N$ such that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic."

But the intended meaning of "any two denumerable models are isomorphic" is "for all $M$ and $N$, if $M$ and $N$ are denumerable models, then $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic".

This is an unfortunate ambiguity in natural language.

> Is it correct to say: if a set of sentences is denumerably categorical, then all denumerable models are isomorphic?

Yes.

I'll also point out that the term "countable" is much more common than "denumerable" for a structure with domain of size $\aleph_0$. And correspondingly, the term "countably categorical" (or "$\aleph_0$-categorical", or sometimes "$\omega$-categorical") is much more common than "denumerably categorical".

Comment: I think the OP's misreading is more subtle. He reads "any" as a universal quantifier, but he reads its scope as being the whole implication. So he ends up with "For all A, B denumerable models of $\Gamma$, (if A is isomorphic to B then $\Gamma$ is denumerably categorical)." To correct this, the first step should probably be the (standard but weird) convention that "if" in a definition means "iff"; once that's understood, the scope problem may vanish on its own.

Comment: Another terminological issue: Some people use "denumerable" to mean "countably infinite" (whereas "countable" allows the possibility of being finite). But my impression is that even those people tend to say "countably categorical" (or "$\aleph_0$-categorical") rather than "denumerably categorical". (Of course it makes no difference for complete theories.)  By the way, is "categoricity in power" the only surviving use of "power" to mean cardinality?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, that's one possible reading of the issue. I think the core trouble is that the natural language interpretation of "any" can differ between in the phrases "If any $x$ is $P$, we say $Q$" and "We say $Q$ if any $x$ is $P$". I tend to read the former as "$Q$ iff there exists an $x$ such that $P(x)$", while I tend to read the latter as $Q$ iff for all $x$, $P(x)$". Maybe I'm wrong about the usual usage in one of these two examples, but I try to avoid the construction because of this possible ambiguity.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I agree; it's better to avoid "any" in negative contexts. Unfortunately, I don't always do that, because I fail to recognize ambiguity in what I myself have written. An example I've used in class: "Anybody can solve this problem" and "everybody can solve this problem" are essentially synonymous, but "if anybody can solve this problem then Joe can" is quite different from "if everybody can solve this problem, then Joe can".

Comment: @AndreasBlass "Categoricity in power" is certainly the only surviving use of "power" for cardinality that I'm aware of. And I think it only survives because it's the title of Morley's highly influential paper. I basically never hear model theorists use the phrase, except when referring directly to that paper.

Answer (score 2):

The fragment you quote is a definition.

> My question is in the other direction: Is it correct to say: if a set
>   of sentences is denumerably categorical, then all denumerable models
>   are isomorphic?

Yes, by definition.

> What does this definition mean?

It means that if there exists a countable model of $\Gamma$, then any other countable model of $\Gamma$ is isomorphic.

The definition you quote is just a special case of categoricity in power, you might try searching for that if you want to understand it.

Comment: Looking it up, I think I'm on the right track with Morley's categoricity theorem? Thanks for the eye-opener.

Comment: Where you wrote "then any other model of $\Gamma$ is isomorphic" you presumably meant "then any other countable model of $\Gamma$ is isomorphic".